# Favicon is not showing

Tags: php, favicon, ico

I have a small problem.

On some of my pages I cannot make favicon to be shown.

On some pages everything is fine, and favicon is shown properly, however on other sites I cannot make the favicon to appear. I tried putting the ico file in the main directory, but without any results.

This file1.php is working fine:

```
<? include("core/config.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="include/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/flavico.fw.ico">
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

However on this one favicon is not showing:

```
<?php include("core/config.php");
include("include/resolution.php"); 
function new_function($nazwa){
global $wys;
global $db;
$wys->some_function($ub,$na,$ub_pod);   
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>title</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/flavico.fw.ico">
<link href="include/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

I assume that this problem is caused by php functions, right?

Comment: I supose the name of the favicon is not right. (having 2 dots in the name)

Comment: Do your php functions output anything? Btw this is [invalid XHTML](http://www.phtml.org), `"...img/flavico.fw.ico" />`, `...rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: It's favicon not flavico

Comment: Why does the first code work then and the second doesn't?
You can check weather the browser requests the icon if you open the console e.g. firebug and watch for favicon or 404 error

Comment: favicon is working ok (even with two dots). The paths are ok because when I check the favicon on the console in both cases browser read the ico right. However on the second side ico isn't appearing.

Comment: Did you check if any source code is displayed above the <!DOCTYPE statement (in your browser or by downloading the HTML delivered by php)?
Did you try to comment out the php code and see if it works (just for tests)?

Comment: Yes, without php code everything is working fine.

Comment: In the source code(in chrome) all code which should be between <head></head> appears after the <body>

Answer (score 3):

Please show urls for both pages.
Guess your problem in relative urls. Assume that first url was http://mysite.org/file1.php and second was http://mysite.org/subsecrion/file2.php
then you should either use absolute path for favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/flavico.fw.ico">
```

or add  tag:

```
<base href="http://mysite.org/">
```

Comment: both pages are in the same directory. http://mypage.org/file1.php and http://mypage.org/file2.php

Comment: Can you show me generated html ( aka "view source" in a browser) ? Maybe included resolution.php do some output and break markup...